# Running SQL script after Visual Studio Publish of Web Application via WebDeploy

Tags: web-applications, deployment, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to publish an MVC web application. I'm generally working in a "database first" sort of way.

As part of my development process, I create a couple of (idempotent) scripts that put the database in a known state - this is mostly the creation of stored procedures, granting permissions, checking that columns exist and inserting reference data. It's not a "create database" type operation.

When I publish the web application to test, I then have to jump on the server to run these scripts.

**Is there a way to automatically run these scripts as a post publish task.**

I can see that clicking on "My Project" gives me an option to "Package/Publish SQL" but I can't seem to find a way to add my scripts without doing a scarey "Auto Script Schema" operation.

And when I publish, it looks at the connection strings and tells me that database updates are not an option for this provider.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it. Or, of course, let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I did wonder if I could create an empty database (on dev and live) and use the schema deployment to do the update to the empty database (and thus leave my database alone), and then run the scripts on this database, bt referencing the proper database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the absence of anything more useful, I have started to use the following:

In App_Data, I have a folder holding a set of scripts.

- One script adds columns and missing tables
- One creates all the stored procedures and grants the permissions
- One adds data where necessary.

The Scripts are published with the rest of the application, and are designed to be idempotent - they can be run as many times as I want and leave the database in the same state after.

It's not an ideal solution as I have to remote desktop to the server and run the scripts, but it's proving to be reasonably reliable and fast.